# In python, how can I find a phrase in a tokenized string?

Tags: python, nltk

Let's say I tokenize a string and turn it into a list:

```
>>> s = "This is a test" 
>>> l = nltk.word_tokenize(s) 
>>> l
['This', 'is', 'a', 'test']
```

How do I then search the list for the occurrence of a phrase like "is a," i.e. 'is' directely followed by 'a'?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what is your high-level goal, what patterns are you trying to find in sentences? Thanks.

Comment: are you trying to implement shingles (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W-shingling) ?

Comment: Actually I have a tokenized and POS-tagged list, and I want to look for constructions like "NN1 of the NN2" and transform it to NN2-NN1. I can POS tag it OK, but then searching for a sequence in a list is tricky, it looks like.

Comment: Maybe overkill, but you could use n-grams. :)

Comment: Why not convert it into a string and do `in check`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to check if two items are in a list and in order:

```
l = ['This', 'is', 'a', 'test']
any(['is', 'a'] == l[i:i+2] for i in xrange(len(l) - 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use regex to first extract the desired pharases such as `is a` and then count the number of elements in that list resulted.This way you don't have to tokenize the string too, if that is a desirre property.

This works for you:

```
import re
dummyList = re.findall(r'\bis a\b', '  This is a test. A regular expression is a necessity to catch all is a(s)')
print len(dummyList)
```

this will print out `3`